# how can my Nginx working on port 8880 and 80 both with different .net core application

Tags: .net, nginx, amazon-ec2, .net-core

I have my server on amazon Ec2 instance and nginx server running on it.

I have 2 projects on this instance

- Project 1

  - running on http://localhost:5005/
  - working fine because it is using default port 80 by hitting http://my-public-ip
- Project 2

  - running on https://localhost:5001/
  - not working don't know what am i missing?

my default files of nginx in sites-available is something like this

Server 1

```
server { 
    listen       80;
    server_name  0.0.0.0;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5005/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Server 2

```
server { 
    listen       8880;
    server_name  0.0.0.0;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         https://localhost:5001/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this work locally?  If so, then it's probably your AWS ingress rules.

Comment: yes it works locally fine @Matthew

Comment: Since it's likely a networking issue, you'll probably get better advice on https://serverfault.com/